# WP7 Pushpin tooltip/bubble

Tags: windows-phone-7, bing-maps, pushpin

I am porting an iPhone app to WP7 which contains a map with several markers/pushpins that I get from a webservice (location, icon and title).

I have setup the XAML required to display the map as well as some code for the pushpin:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="customPushpin" TargetType="my:Pushpin">
        <Image Height="39" Source="Resources/Icons/Pushpins/pinGreen.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="32"/>
    </ControlTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <my:Map Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" x:Name="Map"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" CredentialsProvider="{Binding CredentialsProvider}" 
            CopyrightVisibility="Collapsed" LogoVisibility="Collapsed" Center="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=Center}" 
            ZoomBarVisibility="Visible" 
            ZoomLevel="{Binding Zoom, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <my:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Pushpins}">
            <my:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <my:Pushpin MouseLeftButtonUp="Pushpin_MouseLeftButtonUp" 
                                Location="{Binding Location}" 
                                Template="{StaticResource customPushpin}">                           
                    </my:Pushpin>
                </DataTemplate>
            </my:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </my:MapItemsControl>
    </my:Map>        
</Grid>
```

I am looking for a way to add some sort of bubble when the user clicks on the pushpin. I have looked a bit into infoboxes/tooltips but since they work on hover, that's not something I can use for the phone (tap/click).

I am guessing there's no similar control in WP7 that creates a bubble - how could I go about creating something similar?

Thanks in advance,

Alex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply put a square Border inside LayoutRoot with Visibility="Collapsed", then when you click your pushpin you update its content and make it visible.

Just make sure to put it *after* your map control (otherwise it will be rendered behind the map and will consequently be invisible).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I actually followed a similar approach. I placed a border at the bottom of the screen (with some fancy effects in Blend) that shows up when a user clicks on a pin with the info of said pin.

Comment: I was looking for this too. Too bad there's no built in way to add it next to the bubble. I'm surprised they didn't keep the tooltip and base it on a tab in place of the mouse enter/leave.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to achieve this is to Show/Hide the Content of the Pushpin on Tap  instead of MouseLeftButtonUp because of some performance considerations.

```
void pushPin_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
   this.border.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;

    //stop the event from going to the parent map control
    e.Handled = true;
}

private void map_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
   this.border.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom popup.

A great video that exaplains how to do this is located [here](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/videos/all/creating-a-custom-popup-in-windows-phone-7/).

Answer (score 0):

Other solution is using the ContextMenu from the Silverlight toolkit for Windows Phone!
Just go to the [Coding4Fun](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/) page on CodePlex and download it ( it contains the toolkit ) and in your XAML inside the PushPin definition add following:

```
<map:Pushpin x:Name="currentLocation">
<toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
    <toolkit:ContextMenu IsZoomEnabled="False">
        <toolkit:MenuItem Header="this is menu item 1" Click="MenuItem_Click" />
        <toolkit:MenuItem Header="this is menu item 2" Click="MenuItem_Click" />
        <toolkit:MenuItem Header="this is menu item 3" Click="MenuItem_Click" />
    </toolkit:ContextMenu>
</toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu></map:Pushpin>
```

This way, when you tap and hold the pushpin, you'll get the contectmenu!
( good example also found here: [example](http://jeffblankenburg.com/post/31-Days-of-Windows-Phone-7c-Day-21-Silverlight-Toolkit-for-Windows-Phone.aspx) )